# Logs NOT printing seamlessly/refresh issue while using filters in ddms (Delvik Debug Monitor Systems) from Android SDK

Tags: android, printing, sdk, adb, ddms

Could any one help me find the issue why ddms log does not refresh seamlessly when I create filters?

So explicitly I keeping pressing the filter, then I see the logs.

Otherwise when I am NOT using filters ddms seamlessly prints log when I connect adroid device.

Environment: Windows Vista and Ubuntu (both OS see this issue)